# How to convert Binary into JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm having trouble to convert a binary file in which I have data from a FLASH Memory into a  JSON or a file readable.

I'm trying to read the file this way in Python:

```
fileName = "TST477 DeviceMemory.bin"
with open(fileName, mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = file.read()
print(fileContent)
```

I attach a sample of the data I'm trying to convert:
[Data Sample Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qYBy.png)

And if I try to load it into JSON

```
data = fileContent.decode("utf-8")
s = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

throws the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 8:
invalid continuation byte
```

Please can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: You can `base64` encode it but it would be space inefficient. You can also try decoding using `latin-1` but it would change the content and require careful decoding.

Comment: Have a look at the [binascii](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) library - from the documentation. [This page](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/working-binary-data-python) may also help.